# How to concat item that is in list format in columns in dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, dataframe

i want to concatenate item that is in list format in dataframe

i have a data frame below, when i print the  DataFrame.head(), it shows below

```
A    B
1    [1,2,3,4]    
2    [5,6,7,8]
```

Expect Result (convert it from list to string separate by comma)

```
A    B
1    1,2,3,4
2    5,6,7,8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[1,    [1,2,3,4]],
[2,    [5,6,7,8]]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['A', 'B'])

df['B'] = [','.join(map(str, lst)) for lst in df.B]

print(df.head(2))
```

**Output**

```
   A        B
0  1  1,2,3,4
1  2  5,6,7,8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['1',[1,2,3,4]],['2',[5,6,7,8]]], columns=list('AB'))
```

generic way to convert lists to strings. in your example, your list is of type int but it could be any type that can be represented as a string to join the elements in the list by using `','.join(map(str, a_list))` Then just iterate through the rows in the specific column that cotains the lists you want to join

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[i,'B'] = ','.join(map(str, row['B']))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `map` or `apply` methods for this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[1,    [1,2,3,4]],
[2,    [5,6,7,8]]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['A', 'B'])

df['B'] = df['B'].map(lambda x: ",".join(map(str,x)))
# or 
# df['B'] = df['B'].apply(lambda x: ",".join(map(str,x)))

print(df.head(2))
```